# What's the range of file descriptors on 64-bit Linux?

Tags: c, linux

I'm writing a program using epoll_wait to wait for file descriptors on 64-bit Linux, and I try to put some information together with the file descriptor in the epoll_event user data.

I know in practice it's unlikely that file descriptor will exceed 32 bits. Just wanna know is that kernel guarantees that file descriptors have a specific range, or it just counts from small and unlikely to get very big?

Comment: I would imagine FD numbers are recycled -- e.g. never exceed the highest number of concurrent open descriptors for the process -- but.... I have no clue.

Comment: fd is by definition a"small" non-negative int, whatever "small" means at run time. Beyond that, the kernel makes no guarantees of its value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `epoll_ctl(2)` interface to add new filedescriptors takes an `int fd` argument, so you're already limited to 32-bit range (at least on the Linux platforms I'm familiar with).

You're further limited by `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` system-wide limit on the number of open files for all processes; `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` is currently `595956` on my system.

Each process is further limited via the `setrlimit(2)` `RLIMIT_NOFILE` per-process limit on the number of open files.  1024 is a common `RLIMIT_NOFILE` limit. (It's very easy to change this limit via `/etc/security/limits.conf`.)

It's a rare application that needs more than 1024. The full 32 bits seems unlikely as well, since each open file will take some kernel memory to represent -- four billion ~280 byte `struct inode` structures (at the minimum) is a *lot* of pinned memory.

Comment: Thanks, seems I can safely spare some bit for use then.

Answer (score 3):

Do you plan on having 2 billion file descriptors open, and do you expect the OS to handle this?

In most *nixs, functions that return a FD return it as an `int`, with < 0 being an invalid descriptor. Those functions return FDs in an `int`, so that type's range is the range for FDs. (Minus the negatives (no pun intended)) I'd follow suit: use the same type, thus, `int`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a comment in the kernel indicating the hard upper limit is 1024*1024.

Answer (score -3):

the range of file descriptors on 64-bit (also apply for 32-bit system) Linux is 0 to 1023, you can not create more then 1023 opened file-descriptor. you try to open more then 1023 file-descriptor then system will return error EBADF (Bad file descriptor), error no - 9.

Comment: source/citation?